# Xam.Plugin.Connectivity (by James Montemagno) is disregarding the timeout provided

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, wifi

So here is the scenario: a device is connected to the WIFI network but the WIFI router has no internet access. In other words device is connected to a WIFI network on which internet is not accessible. If I call `await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("https://github.com", msTimeout: 1000);`, the call is taking much longer than 1 second (timeout that I mentioned). Any ideas as to why it is happening? and how can I fix it?

I am using version 3.1.1 available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/).

Comment: How did you use that api. I make my Wifi internal and test it, the parameter can control the timeout with 1 sec or 3 seconds.

Comment: First make sure that your device is connected to a WIFI network. Then disable the internet temporarily on your WIFI router. You can turn it off by logging into your router settings or simply by unplugging the cable from your router's WAN port. Once you have done that, try that API, it will seem to disregard timeout

Answer (score 1):

It is a issue of Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.

IsRemoteReachable function returns the "false" value, instead of returning after the max time.
Someone logged your problem: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/issues/117
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/issues/145